# What are some other uses of class methods in Ruby, other than to just set an attribute/variable of a class?

Tags: ruby

Can you modify a class when you call a class method? Or is it just for setting attributes, like this example.

```
class UnitedStatesPresident

  def self.citizenship

     "United States of America"

 end

end

p UnitedStatesPresident.citizenship
```

Comment: How do you want to modify a class? add a new method or modify the called method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *can* modify a class using a class method. Here's an example that defines a new class method whose purpose is to add a method to the class (itself) after the class has been defined:

```
class UnitedStatesPresident
    def self.citizenship
        "United States of America" # Notice the absence of backticks (`)
    end

    def self.create_method(name, &block)
        self.class.send(:define_method, name, &block)
    end
end

p UnitedStatesPresident.citizenship # => "United States of America"

UnitedStatesPresident.create_method(:name) do
    "Barack Obama"
end

p UnitedStatesPresident.name # => "Barack Obama"
```

For more info, see the documentation: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Module.html#method-i-define_method

EDIT: Notice that the author of the documentation uses #send in the example above to send the #define_method message, which is private. The author does this reluctantly, referring to this style as a "hack."

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can modify a class using a "class method". (Note that actually, there is no such thing as a class method. Class methods are just singleton methods like any other singleton method. And in fact, singleton methods don't exist either, they are just regular instance methods of the singleton class. Or, they are just instance methods of the class of a class, which is `Class` or any of its superclasses (`Module`, `Object`, `BasicObject`).)

In fact, I am surprised that you haven't come across some class methods that modify the class already! Here are some examples:

- `Module#private` without arguments: sets the default visibility for methods defined after it to `private`
- `Module#protected` without arguments: sets the default visibility for methods defined after it to `protected`
- `Module#public` without arguments: sets the default visibility for methods defined after it to `public`
- `Module#attr_reader` generates a getter method
- `Module#attr_writer` generates a setter method
- `Module#attr_accessor` generates a getter/setter method pair
- `Module#include` mixes a module into the inheritance chain as a superclass
- `Module#prepend` mixes a module into the inheritance chain right below
- `Module#alias_method` creates a copy of a method
- `Module#const_set` sets a constant
- `Module#remove_const` removes a constant
- `Module#class_variable_set` sets a class variable
- `Module#remove_class_variable` removes a class variable
- `Module#define_method` defines a method
- `Module#undef_method` undefines a method
- `Module#remove_method` removes a method
- `Module#refine` creates a refinement
- `Module#using` activates a refinement

I am very surprised that you haven't come across `alias_method`, `private` or `attr_*` yet.

Comment: Great answer. So a class method in essence is an instance method of the superclass, ergo when calling `Foo.bar` you are instantiating the super class of Foo?

Comment: No, a class method is an instance method of the class of the class, just like with any other object. If you call `some_array.foo`, the method is looked up in the class of `some_array`, which is `Array`. If you call `some_string.foo`, the method will be looked up in the class of `some_string`, which is `String`. If you call `SomeClass.foo`, the method will be looked up in the class of `SomeClass`, which is `Class`. Either that, or Ruby also has the concept of *singleton class*; each object has its own unique singleton class of which it is the only instance. Methods can also be defined there.

Comment: There is no instantiating going on (unless, of course, you call `new` or `allocate`), and this has nothing to do with the superclass.